# Embedding a CDF on Web page

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cdf-format, html

I'm using Mathematica 12.x, and I have created a CDF, which I tested using Wolfram Player. I'm trying to make it so that I can have the CDF to be used on a web page. I purchased a non-basic Wolfram cloud subscription. Can someone tell me the exact steps that need to be performed so that I can publish the CDF to the cloud? Additionally, once published, how do I make it so that it can be embedded onto an HTLM web page.

Comment: The CDF technology is being deprecated by Wolfram Research. You should look into `CloudDeploy`.

Comment: @Shredderroy Can you tell me where I can find information about the deprecation of CDF. I looked but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Shredderroy, looking at Clouddeploy I don't see how I can embed dynamic content directly on my webpage. The solutions that I have seen show a hyperlink that the user has to click in order to use the dynamic content.

Comment: Unfortunately, there might not be a straightforward solution for what you are seeking to do. `CloudDeploy` and `webMathematica` tend to assume that you are building the entire application in Wolfram Language, not embedding a small applet in an existing application. I have not tried embedding a `CloudDeploy` link in an iframe, but it might work for you.

Comment: You can embed the notebook as an iFrame, take a look at `EmbeddedCode` though I am not sure it produces optimal html/js. Another solution is a wolfram notebook embedder, check on GitHub, but that could be an overkill.